# Returning a Trait implementation using different implementations

Tags: rust, traits

The following implementation seems quite simple. for some reason I don't get what the problem is. Compiler doesn't compile.

The main problem here is that I cannot change the declaration of the function `test(bool)` since it's out of a framework.

```rust
/// Implemented in a 3rd party framework:
trait Share {
    fn dosomething();
}

impl Share for String {
    fn dosomething() {
        todo!()
    }
}

/// My part of the implementation:
// this function `test` will be handed over (as a function) to a framework method, which I can't change it's return type.

fn test(data: bool) -> Result<impl Share, String> {
    return if data {
        Ok(Data {})
    } else {
        Ok("a string".to_string())
    }
}



struct Data {

}

impl Share for Data {
    fn dosomething() {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:12
  |
5 |         Ok("a string".to_string())
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Data`, found struct `String`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Probably a typo. Use `Err` for the `String` not `Ok`

Comment: @prog-fh I think OP really meant `Ok` since `String` implements `Share`.

Comment: The compiler can't know what to return at compile-time when the choice is made at runtime. You need dynamic polymorphism here, not static.

Comment: Why not just Ok("a string") ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both branches of the `if`-`else` expression must evaluate to a value of the same type. However, in your code:

```
fn test(data: bool) -> Result<impl Share, String> {
    return if data {
        Ok(Data {}) // : Result<Data, String>
    } else {
        Ok("a string".to_string()) // : Result<String, String>
    }
}
```

The first branch evaluates to `Ok(Data {})`, and therefore its type would be inferred as `Result<Data, String>`, whereas the second branch evaluates to `Ok("a string".to_string())` and it would be inferred as `Result<String, String>`. Since these types are different, it results in a compile-time error.

---

If `Share` were an [object-safe trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety), e.g.:

```
trait Share {
    fn dosomething(&self);
}
```

Then, since the values `Data{}` and `"a string".to_string()` implement `Share`, you could turn them into *trait objects* by placing them into a `Box<dyn Share>`. This way, you would still achieve a (run-time<sup>X</sup>) type erasure by relying on dynamic polymorphism:

```
fn test(data: bool) -> Result<Box<dyn Share>, String> {
    return if data {
        Ok(Box::new(Data{}))
    } else {
        Ok(Box::new("a string".to_string()))
    }
}
```

Note that here both branch values are of the same type: `Result<Box<dyn Share>, String>` because the types `Box<Share>` and `Box<String>` are *erased* at run-time to `Box<dyn Share>`.

---

<sup>X</sup>You were aiming at a compile-time type erasure with your initial `impl Share`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to provide different types for the `Ok` variant of the result, all of them implementing `Share`, then you have to switch to dynamic polymorphism.

```rust
fn test(data: bool) -> Result<Box<dyn Share>, String> {
    if data {
        Ok(Box::new(Data {}))
    } else {
        Ok(Box::new("a string".to_string()))
    }
}

trait Share {
    fn dosomething(&self);
}

impl Share for String {
    fn dosomething(&self) {
        println!("something on String");
    }
}

struct Data {}

impl Share for Data {
    fn dosomething(&self) {
        println!("something on Data");
    }
}

fn main() {
    if let Ok(s) = test(true) {
        s.dosomething();
    }
    if let Ok(s) = test(false) {
        s.dosomething();
    }
}
```

This implies heap allocation (`Box`) because the value is produced inside the function (you cannot return a reference to a local).

However, if you only want to provide a limited set of types implementing `Share` then, you can return an `enum` instead of `impl Share`.

```rust
enum VariousTypes {
    D(Data),
    S(String),
}

impl Share for VariousTypes {
    fn dosomething(&self) {
        match self {
            Self::D(d) => d.dosomething(),
            Self::S(s) => s.dosomething(),
        }
    }
}

fn test(data: bool) -> Result<VariousTypes, String> {
    if data {
        Ok(VariousTypes::D(Data {}))
    } else {
        Ok(VariousTypes::S("a string".to_string()))
    }
}

trait Share {
    fn dosomething(&self);
}

impl Share for String {
    fn dosomething(&self) {
        println!("something on String");
    }
}

struct Data {}

impl Share for Data {
    fn dosomething(&self) {
        println!("something on Data");
    }
}

fn main() {
    if let Ok(s) = test(true) {
        s.dosomething();
    }
    if let Ok(s) = test(false) {
        s.dosomething();
    }
}
```